# URLs conversion in regex search/replace

Tags: regex, sed, notepad++

How to convert URLs with queries with regex sreach/replace from one form to another? e.g.:

```
http://www.example.com/Something/?a=123.321&b=456.432&c=789.123&primary=true
```

into

```
https://example.net/#?bda=456.432&cfe=789.123&abc=123.321
```

so only paramerers 123.321, 456.432 and 789.123 shoud be keeped.

Comment: With sed, or in notepad++? The regex dialects are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capture each query parameter, and then replace with the captured groups in the output string in your desired format. For example:

```
.+\?\w+=(\d+(?:\.\d+))&\w+=(\d+(?:\.\d+))&\w+=(\d+(?:\.\d+)).+
```

replace with

```
https://example.net/#?bda=\2&cfe=\3&abc=\1
```

https://regex101.com/r/qOGiBK/1

(The `\1`, `\2`, and `\3`s are substituted with the first, second, and third captured group, respectively)